# Chamar uma nova classe IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, classes

Sou novo no ambiente IOS e após estudar um pouco como funciona a linguagem, nao entendi como eu posso chamar uma janela/classe e sobrepor a janela atual como faço no android.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(a.class, b.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Iniciei um aplicativo com controle de abas e pesquisando no stack ingles e em alguns tutoriais na internet, vi que é necessário utilizar um controle de navegação. Ao aplicar o controle de navegacao na view, uso o codigo abaixo para abrir a nova classe.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dicas"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];
```

Funciona mais ela apenas troca a view atual pela nova..ficando igual a imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem algum modo de chamar uma nova janela sem ser desse modo e sem usar controle de navegacao? Por eu estar usando abas na parte inferior ficaria algo estranho um controle de navegacao na parte superior.

Answer (score 1):

A navegação desse app não está estranha, pelo contrário, esse tipo de comportamento é bem comum em apps do iOS.
Entretanto, você não é obrigado a colocar instâncias de `UINavigationController` como filhos da TabBar. Exemplo:

```
UIViewController* controller = [UIViewController new];
[controller setTitle:@"Controller 1"];
UINavigationController *navController = [UINavigationController new];
[navController setTitle:@"Tab 1"];
[navController setViewControllers:@[controller]];

UIViewController* controller2 = [UIViewController new];
[controller2 setTitle:@"Controller 2"];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [UITabBarController new];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:@[navController, controller2]];
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

Nesse exemplo criei uma tab bar com dois filhos: o primeiro é um `UINavigationController`, o segundo um `UIViewController`.

Além de `pushViewController` em um `UINavigationController` como você utilizou, existem outras formas recorrentes de adicionar um view controller na hierarquia. É possível utilizar `presentViewController` que adicionará um controller sobre toda a tela:

```
UIViewController *detailController = [UIViewController new];
[controller2.tabBarController presentViewController:detailController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Caso necessite adicionar um controller com tamanho específico, numa parte qualquer da view do controller atual, assim como faria com um botão por exemplo, utiliza-se o conceito de View Controller Containment. Esse conceito é similar ao de Fragments do Android.

```
UIViewController *detailController = [UIViewController new];
detailController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
[detailController.view setFrame:frame];
[controller2 addChildViewController:detailController];
[controller2.view addSubview:detailController.view];
[detailController didMoveToParentViewController:controller2];
```

Além do código para adicionar a view do novo controller em uma view do controller atual, é necessário informar para ambos a relação de pai/filho. Isso permitirá o controller filho receber os callbacks do ciclo de vida da view do controller pai.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode dar um `presentViewController` que a *view* vai vir de baixo para cima, sem fazer a navegação.